# eJabberd admin still sees user as ONLINE after .disconnect / Android XMPP Smack

Tags: java, android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I'm using eJabberd and Smack for Android (Native Java)
I've been trying to call **.disconnect()** in every imaginable way to disconnect and set the user as OFFLINE, but on eJabberd admin, it's always ONLINE, even after a successful disconnect.
Some codes I used:

`connection.disconnect();`

Also used:

```
    try {
         connection.sendStanza(
               MessageBuilder.buildPresence()
               .ofType(Presence.Type.unavailable)
               .build()
         );
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also:

```
  PresenceBuilder presenceBuilder = connection.getStanzaFactory()
                                .buildPresenceStanza();
                        presenceBuilder.ofType(Presence.Type.unavailable);
                        Presence presence = presenceBuilder.build();
                        try {
                            connection.disconnect(presence);
                        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

All these attempts results in the ConnectionListener trigger the
***public void connectionClosed() {}***

Which means the connection was successfully closed.

**SO WHY IS THIS STILL SHOWING AS ONLINE *(Online Users)* EVEN AFTER SUCCESSFULLY DISCONNECTED?**

My iOS version, whenever I call **[connection disconnect];** and go to my eJabberd admin, the user is shown as OFFLINE (not listed in the Online Users page).

Did I miss something here?

--

**He are the tags Smack is sending to eJabberd server according to its own debugger:**

```
D/SMACK: SENT (1): 
    <presence id='3HD1T-11' type='unavailable'/>
    <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='16'/>
    </stream:stream>

D/SMACK: RECV (1): 
    </stream:stream>

D/SMACK: XMPPConnection closed (XMPPTCPConnection[myuser@ejabberd.mydomain.com/3432235344…3890484] (1))

D/SMACK: RECV (0): 
    <r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>

D/SMACK: SENT (0): 
    <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='16'/>
```

Comment: No ANSWER? Come on.. nobody has any clue about this? :S
Btw, Hiran's answer IS NOT AN ANSWER!

Comment: No one has any clues?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my XMPPManager was connecting/login a user twice with the same login credentials, keeping two different connections for the same user.

So whenever I did `.disconnect();` it was terminating one of the connections, but leaving the other one still online.

My solution was to make my XMPPManager a singleton and allowing only a single user connection at a time.

Since connection is async, if it called twice (for any crazy reason), it would still connect twice the same user.

So I added a static Boolean set to true right after my method connecting starts.
This way I’d know if I already started a connection/login attempt, and not allow another connection while it’s busy connecting:

```
if(busyConnecting) {
       return;
}
busyConnecting = true;
```

We can also use this:

```
XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(false);
XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault(false);
```